# Pyglet vsync doesn't work

Tags: python, pyglet

I'm trying to get pyglet set up, but I can't seem to get vsync to work at all.

`window.set_vsync(True)` does nothing as far as I can tell (as well as `window.set_vsync(False)`).

My application still runs at ~120 FPS either way (note my refresh rate is 60Hz). It does not matter if I am fullscreen or not.

I'm at a loss as to what is going on. I've had similar problems in the past, but nothing seems to work here. Do you have any suggestions?

I'm running Linux Mint 14 with an Nvidia GTX 660M, pyglet 1.2a, and Python 3.4.

```
import pyglet
from pyglet import clock

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600
FPS_LIMIT = 60
UPDATE_INTERVAL = 1 / 30
VSYNC = False

window = pyglet.window.Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
window.set_vsync(VSYNC)
fps_display = pyglet.clock.ClockDisplay()

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    fps_display.draw()

def update(dt):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    clock.schedule_interval(update, UPDATE_INTERVAL)
    pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: This might not be exactly what you ask, but try setting vsync as false and include this : ‘pyglet.clock.set_fps_limit(60)' might be a workaround. I'm not sure though that vsync is working on every systems anyway.